# Sharepoint Calendar Overlay Timezones Don't Match Original Calendar

Tags: calendar, overlay, timezone

I have a main sharepoint site with subsites, and a main calendar. Two of the subsites have calendar apps. I've overlayed the subsite calendars onto the main calendar. Each calendar is set to Eastern Standard Timezone. On the main calendar, however, one of the subsite calendar overlays 'appears' 3 hours ahead. What could be causing this and how do I fix it?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the regional settings of the subsites are on the same timezone.

For example if subsite 1 is on ET and subsite 2 is on AST. Then the events will reflect the timezone values in the Main Calendar.

Comment: Thanks, Amal!  I'm meeting with a site administrator today, and will see if she can view the timezones for each site since I'm not able to.  Appreciate the advice...